# Who is this half Thor, half Iron Man dude in the Spider-Man: Far From Home trailer?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, spider-man-far-from-home

In the new *Spider-Man: Far From Home* [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYYtuKyMtY8), Jake Gyllenhaal is introduced as a new character.

He seems to play a character who appears to be a hero;

- **Who is this character?**
- Are they traditionally a hero/villain?
- What are some of their powers?

Comment: I am oh so tempted to edit the title to "Who is this _mysterious_ character".

Comment: Wikipedia not good enough for ya? ;)

Comment: @Virusbomb: you probably mean *L'uomo di misterio*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to IMDb, [Mysterio](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6320628/fullcredits).

> Jake Gyllenhaal   ... Quentin Beck / Mysterio

He is typically a villain.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysterio#Powers,_abilities,_and_equipment):

> Quentin Beck does not possess superhuman abilities but he is an expert designer of special effects devices and stage illusions, a master hypnotist and magician and an amateur chemist and roboticist. He has extensive knowledge of hand-to-hand combat techniques learned as a stuntman...

Answer (score 3):

That is [Mysterio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysterio), a perennial Spidey villain.

His powers stem from his mastery of special effects and stage illusion, using them to mess with the senses and perceptions of his enemies. He also uses various gasses to do things like dull Spidey's Spider-sense, among other things.

Comment: Fishbowl helmet is very clearly seen at 2:12